Typescript @signalapp/libsignal-client
I’m trying to figure out how to implement the Signal protocol in TypeScript. I’m using @signalapp/libsignal-client, but I can’t find any documentation on how to implement it. I think my current problem is that I always receive PreKeySignalMessage, but I believe I need SignalMessage.
async function sendGroupMessage(
    senderId: string,
    groupMembers: string[],
    message: string,
    sessionStore: SessionStore,
    identityStore: IdentityKeyStore
): Promise<Map<string, CiphertextMessage>> {
    const encryptedMessages = new Map<string, CiphertextMessage>();

    for (const memberId of groupMembers) {
        if (memberId !== senderId) {
            const address = ProtocolAddress.new(memberId, 1);


                const encryptedMessage = await signalEncrypt(
                    Buffer.from(message, 'utf-8'),
                    address,
                    sessionStore,
                    identityStore,
                    new Date()
                );
                encryptedMessages.set(memberId, encryptedMessage);

        }
    }

    return encryptedMessages;
}

async function receiveGroupMessage(
    receiverId: string,
    senderId: string,
    encryptedMessage: CiphertextMessage,
    sessionStore: SessionStore,
    identityStore: IdentityKeyStore
): Promise<string> {
    const address = ProtocolAddress.new(senderId, 1);

    const messageType = encryptedMessage.type();
    switch (messageType) {
        case CiphertextMessageType.Whisper: {
            const signalMessage = SignalMessage.deserialize(encryptedMessage.serialize());
            const decryptedContent = await signalDecrypt(
                signalMessage,
                address,
                sessionStore,
                identityStore
            );
            return decryptedContent.toString('utf-8');
        }
        case CiphertextMessageType.PreKey: {
            console.error("Unexpected PreKeySignalMessage received. The session might not have been established correctly.");
            return "Error: PreKeySignalMessage received instead of SignalMessage.";
        }
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unsupported message type: ${messageType}`);
    }
}

full code
Node.js 18+
Thanks for any help.
I think my current problem is that I always receive PreKeySignalMessage, but I think I need SignalMessage.
